# How to add particular title and description to categories in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to add particular title and meta description for every post and category in my Laravel based website.

So far, I've done the title and description for the posts, but I couldn't figure out how to do it for categories too.

This is the code I used for the posts and it worked:

```
@if(isset($post->title))
  <title>{{ $post->title }}</title>
@else
  <title>{{ $settings->website_name }} - {{ $settings->website_description }}</title>
@endif

@if(isset($post->description))
<meta name="description" content="{{ $post->description }}" />
@else
<meta name="description" content="Example Example Example" />
@endif
```

I tried to do something similar to this for categories too:

```
@if(isset($categories->name) && ($categories->description))
<title>{{ categories->name }}</title>
<meta name="description" content="{{ categories->description }}">
@else
<title>Whatever</title>
<meta name="description" content="Whatever">
@endif
```

In this code, "categories" is the name of my categories table, while "name" and "description" are it's columns.

This is what I have on error_log:

```
#0 /home/example/public_html/example/app/storage/views

/cba078e6a3a6e27c09d6787a6da4672d(22): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(8, 'Undefined varia...', '/home/example/...', 22, Array)
#1 /home/example/public_html/fun/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(38): include('/home/example/...')
#2 /home/example/public_html/fun/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(45): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/home/example/...', Array)
#3 /home/example/public_html/fun/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(100): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->get('/home/example/...', Array)
#4 /home/example/public_html/fun/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(81): Illuminate\View\View->getContents()
#5 /home/example/public_html/fu in /home/gametops/public_html/fun/app/storage/views/cba078e6a3a6e27c09d6787a6da4672d on line 22
```

This is how I get the categories:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle categories" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> {{ Lang::get('category.categories') }} <b class="caret"></b><div class="nav-border-bottom"></div></a>

<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    @foreach ($categories as $category)
                      <a href="{{ URL::to('category') . '/' . slugify($category->name) }}">{{ $category->name }}</a>
                    @endforeach
                </li>
              </ul>
```

Comment: You are missing `isset` in front of `($categories->description)` in your first `@if`. What is your exact error, what is different from what you are expecting?

Comment: I manually wrote this code when I posted here, on my page the code is fine. The problem is when I add this code for categories, I get blank page.

Comment: Go check your log in `app/storage/logs/laravel.log` and maybe your servers `error.log` to see what error you are getting.

Comment: Maybe you just don't have any errors. Kudos! I suppose my 2p here would be that the best way to do this would be to use blade template inheritance, and instead of lots of `@if`s in the layout, define the title/meta stuff as a section that an individual view can override. That way you likely won't need to do any ifs, because if you're on a category page you *know* you have a `$category` variable ready to go. But this suggestion is somewhat changing your architecture, which I understand if you don't fancy doing that.

Comment: Ooh that error looks like it's saying undefined variable - do you maybe need to rename `$categories` to `$category`? You mention that `categories` is the table name, but maybe the single instance name is `$category`?

Comment: I've added the error_log to the main post. Thanks @alexrussell, but this involves too much work, however I really appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: @alexrussell, For a moment I thought that will work, but I've tried that too, it just returns the else value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi if you are using blade then is simple just make is simple if you want to put unique title and description then modifiy blade layout like this

```
<title>@yield('meta_title', 'Default Title')</title>
<meta name="description" content="@yield('meta_description', 'Default Description')" />
```

now in your any views you can call like this

```
@section('meta_title')
    Your title text will go here
@stop

@section('meta_description')
    Your description text will go here
@stop
```

Comment: My categories.blade, starts with this code:
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
<div class="container">

Should I place in after @extends('layouts.master')?

Comment: anywhere you want, try after extends

Comment: FYI @toofast this is pretty much my suggestion from above, and you said you didn't fancy it. Obviously if you do then all good. Just letting you know. (+1 for actually putting the work in to turn it into an answer.)

Comment: Thanks, but I actually don't have a category.blade file, I am getting categories using this code - See main post edited.